# Not getting photos from Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to fetch all the photos from facebook account. But I am unable to fetch it. Whenever i request I get empty array.

```
 @IBAction func shareFacebook(sender: FBSDKLoginButton) {
        sender.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        sender.delegate = self
        sender.loginBehavior = .Native
    }

//Delegate Method
 func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
    {
        print(result.token)
       FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me/photos", parameters: ["fields":"age_range,name,first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"], HTTPMethod: "get").startWithCompletionHandler { (con, res, err) in
        print(res)
        }
}

//Output = <FBSDKAccessToken: 0x12fea99a0>
{
    data =     (
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/me/photos` requires the permission `user_photos`. Make sure you authorize the user with that permission:

```
sender.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_photos"]
```

If it still does not work, make sure you are trying as App Admin and read about Login Review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Also, the `/me/photos` endpoint does not have fields like `age_range`, `name`, `first_name` and so on. That would be the `/me` endpoint only.

Answer (score 0):

```
 FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id,interested_in,gender,birthday,email,age_range,name,picture.width(480).height(480)"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                        print(result)
})
```

Comment: Actually it was the issue of permission. But thanks !!